# Why does react-bootstrap FormGroup component make all child FormControl component uppercase by default?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-form

I created a component called InputField.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';

export class InputField extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FormGroup>
                <FormControl type="text"/>
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
}
```

when I wrap the FormControl component in a FormGroup component it makes all user input uppercase by default.
[image]

When i remove the FormGroup component the default uppercase behavior is removed (which is what i want). Is this the default behavior for components wrapped by the FormGroup component? I checked if there was any onChange methods passed down as props but nothing was added. So I am not sure if that is the default behavior of FormGroup.

Comment: I believe it's because css. Inspect the code and check if it has a `text-transform: uppercase` applied from somewhere.

Comment: That was it! there was some legacy css that made all input field uppercase. Many thank yous!